# How to get pyodbc.connect to prompt?

Tags: python, pyodbc

In my C++ programs, I'm used to the connection process prompting for a missing password or letting you select your own connection.  Whe I use pyodbc.connect(), an exception is generated instead.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#41>", line 1, in <module>
    c=pyodbc.connect('')
Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnectW)')
```

The pyodbc documentation for [Connection Strings](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/ConnectionStrings) states that pyodbc calls the C function [SQLDriverConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715433(VS.85).aspx).  The prompting behavior is controlled by the DriverCompletion parameter, and I can't see a way to set that parameter from Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can, I just checked the source for this and it seems like it always sends SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT.

[See line 88 in connection.cpp](http://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/blob/10ac782c60f8aa92c401963ca363d20f03de0a3e/src/connection.cpp#L88)

Comment: Thank you for that link to the source, it was very informative. I wonder why they don't expose that parameter to Python?